# File used by another program Error when trying to move FIle - Java 8 - CLOSED

Tags: java, java-8, filereader

Sorry if this is too basic, I am very new to Java 8. I am trying to move the file location after doing some file operations in Java. But I am getting an error saying, unable to move because the file is accessed by another program. But it is not. My code is below.

```
String filePath = c:\\oldPath 
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get(filePath))){
    stream.map(String::valueOf).filter(path -> path.startsWith(filePath + "\\Sa")).forEach(e -> {
        /*
         *
         * Doing my stuff
         */
        Files.move(Paths.get(e), Paths.get("C:\\newPath\\SampleFile.txt"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    });
}
```

I tried moving the file after the stream and the for loop still it is giving me the same error.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: a) What is in "Doing my stuff"? b) The move will successively overwrite the destination on every iteration.  You will essentially delete all but the last input file.

Comment: *"But it is not."* - You will find that it is.  The operating system doesn't lie about this sort of thing.  (Sorry, but I can't see what the actual problem is ... but "denial" rarely fixes an IT problem ... so my advice is not to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

For one File I would do something like this:

```
public void moveFile(String sourcePath, String targetPath) throws Exception {
    Files.move(Paths.get(sourcePath), Paths.get(targetPath);
}
```

What do you think to use this function in a loop?

Comment: Can you move the file in a file-explorer? If not, it is accessed by an other program.

are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, actually closing the buffered reader solved the issue